# Unique name for each child process in parallel R

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I would like to find a unique name for each child process when running computations with the parallel package in R. My goal is to do a 'poor mans' parallel output where each process writes to its own file. I can get the nodename with `Sys.info()['nodename']` but I have 8 processes for each node. I can't seem to find a way to identify each process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it! You can use `Sys.getpid()` and the node name together:

```
pid = Sys.getpid()
nodename = tolower(Sys.info()['nodename'])
id = sprintf('%s_%s',nodename,pid)
```

Comment: On multiple nodes the PID isn't guaranteed to be unique. It would be better to combine Sys.info()['nodename'] and Sys.getpid().

Comment: Good call, thats what I was doing already, I've edited my answer